# Please explain log-shipping delta

Tags: monitoring, log-shipping

I am trying to understand how Delta is monitored in log-shipping. We have log-shipping monitoring in place and I am seeing delta increases sometimes for random instances and it drops once database is synchronized. My questions are:

1. What is Delta in log-shipping?
2. What is effect of Delta on log-shipping monitoring?

Please let me know if anymore information is needed.

Thank You for your time.

Comment: IIRC Deta was feature in SQL Server 2000, You have tagged your question as SQL Server 2008

Comment: `I am seeing delta increases` - where are you seeing this?

Comment: @Aaron It is in our monitoring alerts.

Comment: That tells me absolutely nothing.

Comment: I am trying to understand what is Delta in Logshipping?

Comment: Well, [which delta](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa215263%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)? What are your monitoring alerts actually checking for, and at what threshold do they panic? We have no idea what you're monitoring for or why they are deeming this to be alert-worthy, so you have more answers to your questions right now than we do.

Comment: @AaronBertrand: Alert is for log-shipping monitoring and what I believe this delta is set for copy job. I know this is very broad question to begin with. But, all I am trying to understand is is there any specific definition of  Delta in logshipping monitoring.

Comment: Other than the definitions in [the documentation I already pointed out](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa215263%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)?

Comment: What is version and edition of SQL Server in picture.

Comment: @AaronBertrand: Yes if there is any other article or details

Comment: @Shanky we are talking about Sql Server 2008R2

Comment: I dont think there is any DELTA concept in SQL Server 2008 R2 logshipping